# hook_node_access called more than once

Tags: nodes, hooks

I have this very simple implementation of hook_node_access

```
function applx_node_access($node,$op,$account){
    drupal_set_message($node);
}
```

This returns

```
applx_application
forum
article
page
forum
```

And because of this i am not able to proceed further. I'm not sure why it prints the name of all bundles.

Answer (score 6):

`$node` contains all the content-type in your application as value. So, you need to set your node access based on the `$node` value.

```
function hook_node_access($node, $op, $account) {
  $type = is_string($node) ? $node : $node->type;
  if($type == 'forum') {
    //set your permission based on $op value.
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, how do i go about figuring out which content-type a user is trying to access so i can set the node access?

Comment: Oh i see, its like an iteration. Thanks a lot man ;) You're a life(time) saver :)

Answer (score 5):

It happens because the first parameter of [`hook_node_access()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_access/7) could be either:

- A string containing the content type of the node
- A node object

It is a string for the content type when a node doesn't exist yet, for example because it is going to be created.

In fact, the first line of [`node_node_access()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_node_access/7) (the implementation of that hook made from the Node module), is the following one.

```
$type = is_string($node) ? $node : $node->type;
```

Your code needs to check the type of the value passed as first argument, in a similar way.

The hook is invoked multiple times because Drupal is checking what content types should be shown in node/add for the currently logged-in user. In fact, your hook implementation is getting the machine names of the content type defined in that site.

Notice that, in Drupal 8, the first parameter of that hook is always an object implementing the [`NodeInterface`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21node%21src%21NodeInterface.php/interface/NodeInterface/8) interface, so it is not anymore necessary to check the type of the first parameter.